# How to make an object globally accessible in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
global $con;
```

I have saved the database connection object in $con variable.

```
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','database');
```

When I used it inside function it is not accessible. 
For example

```
function getnews($q){
    $q="SELECT * FROM News";
    mysqli_query($link,$q);
}
```

In `getnews()` function with out passing `$link` in function parameter I am not able to use it.

My Question is, how to use `$link` object with out passing it into function as parameter?

Comment: `function getnews($q) use($link){ ...}` try `use` of php

Comment: You dont need $ link in mysqli function as param?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean the same by `$con` and `$link`:

To answer your question: You have to use the `global $con;` statement inside of the function. It then imports the global variable into the scope of this function and you can use it therein.

**However** I want to point out, that using global variables, and also functions that are not bundled in classes with behaviour, are almost always a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `global $con;` in every function where you use the variable. For example:

```
<?php

function init() {
    global $con;
    $con = "test";
}

function showCon() {
    global $con;
    var_dump($con);
}

init();
showCon();
```

Answer (score 0):

If here $link is $con and you want to use it in the function then need to do as below

```
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','database');

function getnews($q){
    $q= "SELECT * FROM News";
    global $con;  // you need to declare $con as global so you can access it in function scope
    mysqli_query($con,$q);
}
```